# Is Y5V okay for decoupling capacitors?

Tags: ceramic

Y5V capacitors are much more temperature dependent, but is that really critical for decoupling capacitors and a product operating over a -40°C to +85°C range maximum (typical -20°C to +55°C)?

The reason I ask this is the cost is much lower, compare 0.8p with 8p per capacitor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the application must operate over a wide temperature range Y5V is not recommended.

Answer (score 6):

You may also want to use more caps or higher capacitance and/or voltage rating than with X5R or X7R, as Y5V capacitance has a dependence on applied voltage as well as temperature.

Comment: Note that X5R and X7R also have a dependence on applied voltage.

Answer (score 6):

Decoupling would be about the only thing I would consider using Y5V for (and only if I didn't have X7R or X5R available).

8p seems expensive. In large volumes, MLCCs in surface-mount should be a fraction of that price.

Comment: ... or, you know, in [single units](https://www.mouser.co.uk/ProductDetail/Wurth-Electronics/885012205050).  I mean, OK, I'd usually avoid an 0402 as I find they're a pain to solder by hand, but I think that's just me...

Comment: @Jules You must be bored, responding to a nearly 8-year-old answer! :)

Comment: Huh.  Didn't even notice.  It was on the front page. :)

Answer (score 4):

I looked some Y5V caps up last week. The money is what you get, they are very cheap, and very bad. They might lose about 80% or their capacity over temperature or voltage. Depending if you need the capacity, you might be better of spending a bit more on X5R.

Comment: Some small (0201) X5R caps also loose more than 80% of their capacitance with a bias voltage even smaller than half the rated voltage.

Answer (score 2):

For decoupling purposes the variation in value is practically irrelevant. The standard practice is to specify .1uF, but there's nothing inherent in that number that makes it right for this purpose, and it could just as well be .22uF or .047uF. In other words a change of a factor of 2 won't really make any difference. So yes the Y5V is perfectly fine for decoupling. In the majority of digital electronics applications, the value isn't so important, as long as it's "big enough", so just use whatever you can find. If you're worried about the possible loss of capacitance at high temp (-80% for Y5V) then just select a larger value like .15uF or .22uF.